# Renaming columns of dataframe list in Pandas

Tags: python, for-loop, pandas, rename, dataframe

I have a list with lots of dataframes

```
col = ['open', 'high', 'low', 'close']
index = [1, 2, 3, 4]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=col, index=index)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=col, index=index)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=col, index=index)

dflist = [df1, df2, df3]
```

I need to rename all the columns of all the dataframes in the list. I need to add the name of each dataframe to the name of each column. I tried to do it with a for loop.

```
for key in dflist:
    key.rename(columns=lambda x: key+x)
```

Obviously, this is not working. The desired output would be:

```
In  [1]: df1.columns.tolist()
Out [2]: ['df1open', 'df1high', 'df1low', 'df1close']

In  [3]: df2.columns.tolist()
Out [4]: ['df2open', 'df2high', 'df2low', 'df2close']

In  [5]: df3.columns.tolist()
Out [6]: ['df3open', 'df3high', 'df3low', 'df3close']
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use a dict instead of a list to store the DataFrames, if you need to somehow access their "names" and manipulate them programmatically (think when you have thousands of them). Also note the use of the `inplace` argument, which is common in pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

col = ['open', 'high', 'low', 'close']
index = [1, 2, 3, 4]

df_all = {'df1': pd.DataFrame(columns=col, index=index),
          'df2': pd.DataFrame(columns=col, index=index), 
          'df3': pd.DataFrame(columns=col, index=index)}

for key, df in df_all.iteritems():
    df.rename(columns=lambda x: key+x, inplace=True)

print df_all['df1'].columns.tolist()
```

Output:

```
['df1open', 'df1high', 'df1low', 'df1close']
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues here. Firstly, `dflist` is the list of DataFrames, as opposed to the *names* of those DataFrames. So `df1` is not the same as `"df1"`, which means that `key + x` isn't a string concatenation.

Secondly, the `rename()` function returns a new DataFrame. So you have to pass the `inplace=True` parameter to overwrite the existing column names.

Try this instead:

```
dflist = ['df1', 'df2', 'df3']
for key in dflist:
    df = eval(key)
    df.rename(columns=lambda x: key+x, inplace=True)
```